# Phone doesn't recognize usb

Tags: usb-connection-mode, usb-on-the-go

Mine phone (Honor 10) doensn't recognize an usb connection, execept for charging.
The initial problem was connecting my phone to a 3D-printer.
Because this didn't work, I tried to connect a usb-flash disk to the phone with an OTG adapter. The usb-flash disk has a led. It flicks 2 times and that is it. Doesn't recognize the disk.

Things i tried:

My phone should be OTG capable -- I downloaded 2 OTG checker apps

The disk/3D-printer/OTG adapter are working correctly as i checked with my new phone (wich i don't want to use)

I turned on USB debugging in the development settings

Anyone who can help me?
Thanks in advance